# image grid is dropping to next line rapidly

Tags: html, css

I can't keep my image grid from dropping to the next line when resized. I've tried a bunch of different appraoches, including using DIV tags instead of span.. I think it's when the text is dropping a line. Any ideas what's wrong? See gif of what the problem is: 
[imagejumpinggif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8p3T.gif)

Here's the snippet:

CSS:

```
.house {
    width: 23%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.house_container {
    @include span-columns(12);
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.house_illustration {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3%;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="house_container">
  <span class="house"><img src="img/house1.gif" class="house_illustration"/>
  <p class="label">0-2500 sq ft<br> $275 </p> </span>
  <span class="house"><img src="img/house1.gif" class="house_illustration"/>
  <p class="label">2501-3000 sq ft<br> $300 </p> </span>
```

etc.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pm2au3yt/  ---although, it doesn't show the problem. I'm also using SASS - bourbon / bourbon neat. Could be something to do with the way that's compiling the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the second row is getting caught on the 2nd house span on the top row while it's resizing. If this is the problem, this should fix it:

```
.house:nth-child(4n+1){ clear:left; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/17e5asgk/